# System encountered problem

Tags: 12.10

Recently I updated to Ubuntu 12.10 and am frequently getting the System encountered problem dialogue. It is related to the Datacard modem connectivity problem. Kindly please anyone say if anybody encountered the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Do you get any other signs apart from the dialogue coming up. If not then it's probably just old crash logs not getting cleared up. To stop the dialogue appearing hold down alt and press f2 and copy and paste 
`gksu rm -rf /var/crash/*`
Into the search bar that comes up. Then press enter. A box asking for your password will appear, type it in and click OK, nothing will happen, but the dialogue should stop appearing.

Comment: Let me give it a try

Comment: It is throwing error as -r as invalid option

Comment: @AmGates, weird, are you copying the command exactly? -r is definitely a valid option for rm.

Comment: Yes I copied the exact command